# Conditional Statements in Outlook - Targeting multiple versions in one statement

Tags: html, email, outlook, conditional-statements, html-email

I am coding an email and need to target specific versions of Outlook to fix some irregularities. These irregularities affect several versions:

- Outlook 2007 (version 12)
- Outlook 2010 (version 14)
- Outlook 2013 (version 15)

Normally I would be able to use the following to conditionally target these versions:

```
<!--[if gte mso 12]>
CONTENT 
<![endif]-->
```

however I do *not* want to target Outlook 2011 or 2016 (version 16), which using `gte` would end up targeting, and I do *not* want to target 2007 and earlier, which using `lte` would end up targeting.

This is a 2 part question

1. How can I write a conditional code to say `<!--[if mso 12 OR mso 14 OR mso 15]>` without having to write the actual conditional content for each version in a lengthy, messy string of code such as:

   `<!--[if mso 12]> One version of my content in multiple tables and cells <![endif]-->`

   `<!--[if mso 14]> Another version of my content with even more tables and cells <![endif]-->`
2. How can I specifically *not* target Outlook 2011, which is also version 14. NB: I'm 99% sure it's not possible to do that, but thought I'd ask whilst I'm here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you would need to differentiate like that, but use the following:

`<!--[if (mso 12)|(mso 14)|(mso15)]>your code<![endif]-->`

references:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment

https://litmus.com/community/code/396-conditional-code-for-outlook

Comment: That's perfect. Long coding-story as to why I need to target like that, but your end solution makes it much easier than writing conditional content for every version I want to target.

Comment: is nesting possible?